# Why don't websites say "incorrect password"?

Tags: passwords, login, username

When I try to log into a website & I input incorrect login details, why does it say "username **or** password is incorrect"? Why does it not specify which?

Comment: Because one or the other would prove that an account exists or not and thus leak information that could be used by attackers.

Comment: Don't knock the question. if you're not terribly security-aware it's a reasonable request.

Comment: Reasonable but IMO much better suited here https://security.stackexchange.com/ and kind of off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

This is an elementary security measure. By not telling you which is incorrect, it leaves one less attack vector for a bad actor.

Hackers could be bombarding the server with a mathematical set of 'guesswork' login details. By not telling you *which* is incorrect, it means the hacker doesn't know if they're found a real account & therefore just need to hack the password, or if the account doesn't exist at all.

This makes it a) harder to hack & b) more likely they won't bother.

Comment: 100% agree.  There may also be a secondary reason - Its often easier to verify that the username + password hash exist for a user (1 database query) compared to a lookup of username and a second query for password - which would be neccessary to determine which is incorrect. (of-course, this is very design dependant and may not be relevant.)